# Safe Browsing Lookup API to return just true or false?

Tags: php

I was looking for api's that would check urls for malware. I found `Safe Browsing Lookup API` and i want to do something like so:

1) In php pass the url to this api
2) Get the response from api - 1(or true) if it doesnt have malware, 0(or false) if it has malware.

How can i do that? Do i need to make a DOM document and then parse the result? I tried reading the Developer's Guide but i didnt see anything that would help me (maybe im blind).

Any suggestions?

Edit: The API i was using was Google Safe Browsing (https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/)

Comment: What specific API are you talking about? Any links?

Comment: Sorry, ill edit OP. I was talking about google safe browsin API (Thats the only i managed to find)

Comment: Have you checked http://webmasters.stackexchange.com ? I am not sure that this is a coding question as much as it is a question about general webmaster-type issues. Please clarify if I have misunderstood.

Comment: Hmm, i think its a coding question because im looking for advice on how i should get the data that i need. I though i need to conver the html page into dom and then parse the needed data, but maybe im wrong and someone could give a better advice. Or maybe someone used a similar API and could tell me about it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at WOT api - http://www.mywot.com/wiki/API

Wot is a community powered service and I had good experience developing with its api in the past.